# Views with tables have different column width with same setting

Tags: views

I'm having problems with drupal views. I used a table to make a list of items with an image, a title and a body each. The first time I tried it it worked perfectly, each column only taking the necessary space but when I tried to recreate it, the title column is very wide. I check all the settings in both the views and the content and they are the exact same.

Here is the first table
[image]
And this is what the new ones look like
[image]
Do you know why that could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is html table generic behaviour, as browser's determining [widths of individual table cells are a complicated matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150154/how-is-column-width-determined-in-browser).  You would get the same widths if your columns had the same contents inside but since some columns are different you are getting different column widths.

Drupal views *table display style* outputs generic tables without any width specified.  You can influence widths by using something like the following in your theme's css

```
table.views-table td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 150px;
}
```

Above specifies width for the 2nd `TD` tag of a views table. Change position of TD and width to your liking.